# Criar vários select options com Jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

Bom tarde, o que estou a tentar fazer é um botão onde ao clicar cria um select option, mas posso criar as vezes que quiser.

o meu select com ligação à base de dados;

```
<select name="produto_tipo">
  <?php while($row2=$stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)):;?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row2[0];?>"><?php echo $row2[1];?><?php echo $row2[2]."$"; ?></option>
  <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

o meu botão;

```
<button  class='w3-bar-item w3-button'>Inserir Produto</button>
```

A parte Jquery não sei como fazer já andei a pesquisar na net não encontrei o que queria, só criar novos inputs e textos mas tentei implementar e não deu em nada.

Se houver uma alternativa melhor gostava de saber.

Comment: Você quer criar uma opção a mais dentro do select option ou um select option a mais a cada clique?

Answer (score 1):

Da pra fazer somente usando javascript.

```js
  var button = document.querySelector("#button");
  var select = document.querySelector("#select");
  button.onclick = adicionaOption;

  function adicionaOption(){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    var textOption = document.createTextNode('option');
    option.appendChild(textOption);
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
```

```html
<select name="" id="select">
    <option value="">teste</option>
  </select>
  <button id="button">Add</button>
```